# Why does Apple recommend using a runloop over GCD for fetching multiple images?

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

Is it a good idea to load images (1 block each) through Grand Central Dispatch in iOS 4.0? (for use in a UITableView)

Why is a runloop preferred by Apple, as illustrated in the WWDC video sessions 207 and 208?

Comment: In 2007 GCD didn't exist. It's much easier.

Comment: Session 207-207 from WWDC 2010 though, not 2007

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point being made in those videos was that Foundation networking does not integrate well with Grand Central Dispatch right now, so if you want to do Foundation-based networking a runloop is your best bet for avoiding the problems of traditional threads.  However, in Session 206 - "Introducing Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch on iPhone", you'll see that they show an example of how to use GCD for just this purpose.

Me, I prefer GCD because of the elegance of the code and because (as they state in those videos) it is the way of the future.

Comment: GCD doens't work well with Foundation-based networking? Than what can one use? and, how does it differ from Foundation-based networking API? Thank you

Comment: @Henry - When working with GCD, I believe that you would use the CFNetwork functions, rather than classes like NSURLConnection.  The runloop-based approach in WWDC 2010 Session 208 is pretty interesting, though.

Comment: thanks Brad, so what would you recommend a newbie to use? GCD w/ CFNetwork functions, or runloop with NSURLConnection with runloop?

Comment: and where does NSOperation fit in the whole picture? thank you!

Comment: @Henry - Honestly, for a newbie I'd suggest looking at a wrapper like ASIHTTPRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ .  I've only started integrating GCD with my applications (although I use NSOperation all the time), and the runloop approach is fairly new to me.  For general concurrency tasks, I'd read up on NSOperation first, then GCD.

Comment: Thanks, one thing I don't understand about the runloop approach is, how can I download 2 images at a time to reduce latency?

Comment: @Henry - Again, I've not worked with the runloop-based approach.  I highly recommend watching the session 208 video closely to understand Apple's take on this.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't watched those videos yet, but here is what Chris Hanson (Apple Engineer) [says about GCD vs NSOperation](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=232)

> Always use the highest-level
>   abstraction available to you, and drop
>   down to lower-level abstractions when
>   measurement shows that they are
>   needed.

In other words, you should be using NSOperations to do asynchronous processing (such as loading images for a table view) unless you have a good and necessary reason to go for GCD.

Comment: In this case, the overhead for creation of an NSOperation and placement of it in a queue may add up across all the table view rows, so the more lightweight blocks might be preferable.  Blocks and GCD might also simplify his code for this task.